# plotting multiple plots generated inside a for loop on the same axess

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

My code  is as follows, the problem is instead of having one plot, I get 242 plots. I tried putting the `plt.show()` outside the loop, it didn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

names = list()

with open('selected.csv','rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in reader:
        names.append(row[0])

names.pop(0)

for j in range(len(names)):
    filename = '/home/mh/Masters_Project/Sigma/%s.dat' %(names[j])
    average, sigma = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols = (0,1), unpack = True, delimiter = ' ')
    name = '%s' %(names[j]) 
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('Magnitude(average)', fontsize = 16)
    plt.ylabel('$\sigma$', fontsize = 16)
    plt.plot(average, sigma, marker = '+', linestyle = '', label = name)
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: you should not use `for i in range(len(xs))` and `xs[i]` to iterate over elements of an array. Use `for x in xs:`.
Another Point: Why do you use such a complicated way for reading in the names? 
`names = np.genfromtxt("selected.csv", delimiter=" ", dtype=np.str, skiprows=1)`

Comment: Thanks very much. Usually I don't work with csv files, but your way is a short and neat way of doing.

Answer (score 28):

Your issue is that you're creating a new figure with every iteration using [`plt.figure()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure). Remove this line from your `for` loop and it should work fine, as this short example below shows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

for a in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]:
    plt.plot(x, a*x)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Thanks, noted.Is there a way of avoiding for loops?

Comment: @MichaelHlabathe that is a different question entirely to the one you've asked. I would suggest you ask a new question in this case, rather than me editing my answer to answer something different.

Answer (score 4):

Let me improve your code a bit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set the font size globally to get the ticklabels big too:
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 16

# use numpy to read in the names
names = np.genfromtxt("selected.csv", delimiter=" ", dtype=np.str, skiprows=1)

# not necessary butyou might want to add options to the figure
plt.figure()

# don't use a for i in range loop to loop over array elements
for name in names:
    # use the format function
    filename = '/home/mh/Masters_Project/Sigma/{}.dat'.format(name)

    # use genfromtxt because of better error handling (missing numbers, etc)
    average, sigma = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols = (0,1), unpack = True, delimiter = ' ')

    plt.xlabel('Magnitude(average)')
    plt.ylabel('$\sigma$')
    plt.plot(average, sigma, marker = '+', linestyle = '', label = name)

plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's the first time i come across genfromtxt, it is handy and thanks for the update